# Laravel - Order by pivot value in Many to Many table relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot

My application (Laravel 5.0) has a Products table and a Formats table. There's a manyToMany relationship between these two table (format_product). One product can be sold in many formats. Each relationship has a specific price so I have added a "price" column in the format_product table.

Now I'm trying to **sort the products by price** (being the cheapest format-price of each product the reference value).
One more thing, I need to paginate the results.

```
class Product extends Model {

    public function formats()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Format')->withPivot('price')->orderBy('pivot_price', 'asc');
    }

}

class Format extends Model {

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('price');
    }

}
```

This is the format_product_pivot:

```
Schema::create('format_product', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('format_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('format_id')->references('id')->on('formats')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
});
```

In example, having this values:

```
Product A - Format 1 = 15€
Product A - Format 2 = 10€
Product B - Format 1 =  8€
Product B - Format 2 = 20€
Product C - Format 3 =  5€
Product C - Format 1 =  2€
```

I want this result:

```
Product C - 1 ( 2€)
Product B - 1 ( 8€)
Product A - 2 (10€)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I needed. I was aware of the limitation in sorting by a relationship value. As you say, it's the same problem as with multidimensional arrays...
I guess I was trying to find the most laravel-elegant way to address the problem. About adding an orderBy in the model relationships. This way I don't need to order them every time I query the formats of a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I don't typically put `orderBy()` in my model, but it shouldn't be too much of an issue.  You're going to have to use a join to get the results you want.

You can use the following query in your controller:

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::join('format_product', 'format_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                        ->select('products.id', 'format_product.format_id', 'format_product.price')
                        ->orderBy('format_product.price', 'asc')
                        ->paginate(25)
                        ->get();
}
```

The reason you can't sort products by a relationship is the same reason you can't sort a multidimensional array by an inner array.

For example:

```
$array = [
    'key1' => [
        'anotherKey' => 'some value'
    ],
    'key2' => [
        'anotherKey' => 'some other value',
        'anotherKey2' => 'some other value2'
    ],
    'key3' => [
        'anotherKey' => 'yet another value'
    ]
]
```

You can't sort this array by `anotherKey`.  You have to use a join.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just in case somebody copy-paste the code, there's a spelling error, it should be 'products.id' in the select statement.